# OpenCV Python Error Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)

Tags: python, opencv

I just started playing around with `OpenCV` in Python and am running into an assertion error. I copied the following code from a [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video), but it's not working for me.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0) # use first webcam
if not cap.isOpened(): cap.open()

while True:
   # capture frame-by-frame
   ret, frame = cap.read()

   # our operations on the frame come here
   gray = cv.cvtColor(frame,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# display the resulting frame
cv.imshow('frame', gray)
if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
# when everything is done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

When running, I get `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor`

When printing the variables `ret` and `frame` from above, I get `(False,None)`, so it's not even capturing the frame correctly.

What exactly is the issue, and how can I resolve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `ret, frame = cap.read()`, add `if not ret: continue`.

Some cam-drivers return an invalid first frame.