# OpenCV - face and eyes detection error keeps comign up

Tags: python, computer-vision, face-detection

I'm new to programming and machine learning. When I followed a tutorial and tried to run the code. However an error keeps coming up and I can't make it to work.

error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor.

```py
import cv2

# Loading the cascades
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\Cam\Summer/ research\Computer_Vision_A_Z/Module_1_Face_Recognition/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\Cam\Summer/ research\Computer_Vision_A_Z/Module_1_Face_Recognition/haarcascade_eye.xml')

# Defining a function that will do the detections
def detect(gray, frame): 
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] # Zone of interest
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.1, 3)
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes: 
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    return frame

# Doing some Face Recognition with the webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    canvas = detect(gray, frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The only line that *doesn't* get executed if there is no image is `cv2.cvtColor`. You either need to indent the rest of the lines in that loop, or change the condition to `break` on `not ret`.

Comment: So you're still not getting a (color) frame. Are you getting a frame at all? If so, how many channels is it?

Comment: No I'm getting nothing at all. Sorry for the trouble I'm very new to all these. If I run the original code as commented above. I get the error 
error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor

Comment: So you're saying `ret` is `True` and `frame` is `None`?

Comment: I've pasted on my original code above (last part copied from some video-capturing tutorial) . In this case how would I make change to correct the error? Thanks.
error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor

Comment: As I asked in my previous comment, what are the values of `ret` and `frame` after you call `cap.read()`? All of this is caused by passing an invalid frame to `cv2.cvtColor`. It is either empty (`ret == False` and `frame == None`), or the number of channels (the third value in `frame.shape`) is not 3 or 4.

Comment: ret is False and frame is None ... yes it's empty ... how do I fix it

Comment: If `cap.read()` didn't work, what's the only line before that? `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` Does your program check to see if that executed correctly and opened the camera? I would suggest using a better tutorial (maybe [this one](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)) and taking things one step at a time. You could also check [these similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cv2.VideoCapture+cv2.cvtColor+%22-215%22+is%3Aq) and see if anything there helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV Python Error Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752002/opencv-python-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4)